# CSS Style sheet not loading in asp.net mvc using Razor

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have used these lines inside head tag

```
 <link href="~/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Bootstrap seems to work, but site.css is not loading..I even tried

```
<link href='@Url.Content("~/Content/site.css")' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I couldn't find any solution. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you using layout page? Try clearing browser cache and see HTML source in browser inspector to find out if the path points to right folder containing CSS file, because the standard `Url.Content` working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks! it seemed to work